# Bookmark Icon for a website

Tags: icons, favicon, bookmarks

[image: Icons]

I do have a Favicon on my website, and it shows up on the address bar.
But I was curious how to get these big icons when you bookmark a page.  Is a different thing or did I do the favicon wrong?

As you can see, Behance, LinkedIn, and others have a big icon when bookmarked and my website on the left has none.

```
<link rel="icon" href="icons/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need different icons:

- Safari on Mac OS Yosemite (apparently, what you are using): it takes the [Apple Touch icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html). At least, make sure to create a 180x180 icon.
- Chrome: since a few versions, Chrome takes the [Open Graph image](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) (the same icon you use to indicate to Facebook which image to use when a visitor shares your page). Note that Chrome might take something else if it can't find the OG image. Rules are not clear.
- Some other browsers: apparently, some browsers, such as Firefox, have default icons for famous web sites but generate miniatures for the other bookmarks. I can't be 100% sure of this, but I couldn't find any documentation about that. This is just guess work.