# How do I make a custom 'add a site' image for my site in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox

Youtube, Amazon, and a few other sites have a full bookmark image showing for their website. Mine is only showing my .ico. How do I code in a custom image for my blog? Is there meta tag for it? Thanks.

[image]

Edit:

Here is a screenshot of http://iconhandbook.co.uk/ in "Top Sites" in Firefox mobile: [image]

Here is the same websites icon file:
http://iconhandbook.co.uk/favicon.ico
Take the time to look at their source code for their other icons.

So again my question: How do I get the same result as this website?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following extension to customize the image shown for pinned tiles, among other things.

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/new-tab-tools/

Answer (score 0):

I've just researched your question and there's result:
No, you can't add your custom bookmark icon. It's only available for big companies now.

There's no meta-tag for it. But you can try to do these things:

1. Change og:image of your blog. Possible it can help you with Chrome as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649283/bookmark-icon-for-a-website)
2. Add more apple-icon resolutions and android | wp icons
3. Fill your favicon by bg-color. I've tested some sites on Firefox iOS and found that's one, who has single-tone background and looks like you want.

I hope it helps you

[image: iOS screenshot]

Comment: Then how do you explain this website having a custom one?
 Load it in Firefox mobile, then look at 'top sites'. They have a full image icon there. http://iconhandbook.co.uk/

Comment: Hm, if you just want to increase size of your favicon then you should use apple-touch-icon and additional big favicons (72x72 and more). That's only thing made on this site. But you can't manually change the background of the bookmark icon. Firefox will automatically generate ones based on your icon. In this case there's apple 114x114 icon and auto-generated black background. No anything more

Comment: I already tried that. It didn't work. The website I mentioned above has an icon different from what is displayed on mobile. I'm going to add screenshots either above or below this comment to show you want I mean.